# Unable to update value in Tkinter

Tags: tkinter, refresh

I have been working on my final year project for a while now but have become a little stuck for the past week now

I am designing a Temperature controller and so far have the temperature displayed on the main screen with a few other elements to it

But the problem I have is the temperature only stays at the value it was when the program is first run (it doesn't change value)

Below is part of the code I'm struggling with:

```
from gpiozero import MCP3008

adc = MCP3008(channel =0, device =0)

voltage = 3.3 * adc.value

ActualTemp = voltage * 100

ACTEMP ='{:.2f}'.format(ActualTemp)


ttk.Label(mainframe, text= ACTEMP).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))
```

I have tried searching and guessing for days but unable to find anything

Any help would be gratefully appreciated

Thanks

Here is the complete code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from gpiozero import MCP3008

adc = MCP3008(channel =0, device =0)
voltage = 3.3 * adc.value
ActualTemp = voltage * 100
ACTEMP ='{:.2f}'.format(ActualTemp)

FanSpeedDigital = MCP3008(channel =1, device =0)
FanSpeedAnalogue1 = 3.3 * 30.3030303 * FanSpeedDigital.value
FanSpeedAnalogue ='{:.2f}'.format(FanSpeedAnalogue1)


root = Tk()
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 6")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

root.title("Circulation Water Temperature Regulator")


ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Circulation Water Temperature").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(W, E))


ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Actual Temp").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=(W, E))

temp_label = ttk.Label(mainframe);
temp_label.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E));
temp_label.configure(text = ACTEMP)


ttk.Label(mainframe, text="°C ").grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=W)


AutoContol = Button(mainframe, text="Auto Control").grid(column=4, row=2, sticky=(W, E))


ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Set Temperature").grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=(W, E))


SetTemp = StringVar()
SetTemp_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=17,textvariable=SetTemp)
SetTemp_entry.grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=(W, E))


ttk.Label(mainframe, text="°C ").grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=W)


ManFullSpeed = Button(mainframe, text="Manual Full Speed").grid(column=4, row=3, sticky=(W, E))
Entr = Button(mainframe, text="Enter").grid(column=2, row=4, sticky=(W, E))


ttk.Label(mainframe, text='Fan Speed').grid(column=1, row=6, sticky=(W, E))


FanSpeed = ttk.Label(mainframe, width=17,text = FanSpeedAnalogue)
FanSpeed.grid(column=2, row=6, sticky=(W, E))


ttk.Label(mainframe, text="%").grid(column=3, row=6, sticky=W)


for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=15, pady=15)


root.update_idletasks
```

You may not be able to run this code, as I have an analogue to digital converter attached to my Raspberry Pi, which is where im getting my Temperature reading from

Thanks

Comment: Please post minimal BUT runable code. In your code mainframe is not defined and it is hard to help you if we don't know how your code is structured, i.e. how mainframe is defined.

Comment: in order to change the text in the label you need to keep a reference to it, so you probably want to put something like: `temp_label=ttk.Label(mainframe); temp_label.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E));` and then after you calculate your temperature each time call something like `temp_label.configure(text=ACTEMP)`

Comment: Hi Guys, I have edited my post which now includes the full code, As you can see in the code i have tried the code you suggested James but still no luck. I have seen posts which say about using the get() function, would this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting that in your code just before calling `root.mainloop()` :

```
def get_temperature():
    """returns the current temperature"""

    voltage = 3.3 * adc.value
    ActualTemp = voltage * 100
    ACTEMP ='{:.2f}'.format(ActualTemp)
    return ACTEMP


def update_temperature():
    """updates the text"""

    temp_label.configure(text = get_temperature())
    root.after(100, update_temperature)

root.after(100, update_temperature)
```

And this before your mainloop :

`root.after(100, update_temperature)`

The `after` method will call your function every 100 ms, you can change this value according to your needs.